# Why am i getting a 503 error on file upload

Tags: php, cakephp, http-status-code-503

When i upload files with a file size of 50mb it works, but when i try to upload a file above this for example 100mb i'm getting a 503 error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm also getting this in the apache error_log

[Wed Nov 09 17:40:06.856493 2022] [lsapi:error] [pid 18656:tid 47964705101568] [client 175.176.38.142:61062] [host abc.xyz.com] Backend error on sending request(POST /portal/orders/upload_file HTTP/2.0); uri(/webroot/index.php) content-length(153052003) (lsphp is killed?): SendRequest: write to backend socket failed: errno 32

Comment: What did the error log have to say about the _reason_? It might not be due to PHP settings, the webserver might apply limits to the maximum size of POST requests as well.

Comment: CBroe sorry i just updated my post with the apache error_log, your help is appreciated

Comment: Check Apache config files for `LimitRequestBody`...

Comment: Yes the hosting set it to 0 but not working still getting the error, they don't know either